# How can I get final HTML string on iOS

Tags: html, ios, objective-c

I need get HTML from a web. But when I use below code, it only show small HTML with Javascript, not is the full, final HTML, what I see on web browser.

I use this code:

```
NSString* urlString = @"http://mywebsite.com";
NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
```

It also get same result when I use AFNetworking.

How can I get full HTML?

Comment: What more are you expecting? Keep in mind that the website could be returning the HTML normally sent to a mobile device as opposed to what you would see on a computer.

Comment: @rmaddy In browser, I see web has image. But in html return, I don't see image link.

Comment: A real browser downloads the main URL and and referenced Javascript files and then runs the Javascript. That javascript could be making changes to the page. Simply downloading a URL (using the code you posted) makes no attempt to access or execute any Javascript referenced in the main page.

Answer (score 1):

I have answer for my question. I use a UIWebView to load this web page. On finish delegate, I can get full HTML by below code:

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    webview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com"]]];
    webview.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:webview];

}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSString *yourHTMLSourceCodeString = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.outerHTML"];
    NSLog(@"Did finish load: %@", yourHTMLSourceCodeString);
}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {

}

@end
```